# In Delphi is there a point to declare a parameter of type object as const?

Tags: delphi, constants

I know the benefits of `const` parameters for simple types and strings in Delphi. But what about a `const TStrings`? Since a `const TStrings` parameter can have its items (content) changed, what's the point of declaring a `const TStrings` parameter for example? This applies to any object too.

Comment: As a parameter signature it tells me I'm not altering the TStrings in that method. It extends the simple types (const/var/out/<copy>) but isn't enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @FredS There is no value in knowing that the pointer won't be modified inside the method.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Certainly there is a benefit in knowing that the TStrings inside that method is treated as readonly.

Comment: @FredS No, there really isn't.

Comment: For what it's worth you *shouldn't* use `const` when passing an interface variable - only because of a quirk (i.e. bug) in Delphi that it suppresses calling `.AddRef` on the interface when it is passed as `const`. Not calling `.AddRef` completely violates the rules of COM, and can lead to some gotchas (i.e. memory leaks)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `const` applies only to the pointer to the `TStrings` object, not to the `TStrings` object itself.  So it really makes little difference on non-ARC based platforms, especially if the code does not try to change where the pointer is pointing to. It's only real use is to document the *intention* of the parameter.

But, the `const` can make a BIG difference on ARC-based platforms. It disables implicit reference counting on the object that is passed to the parameter (just as `const` does for string and interface parameters).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what is an ARC platform?

Comment: @AlexV [Automatic Reference Counting](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers). Delphi `TObject`-based objects use ARC for lifetime management on iOS and Android, and on Linux prior to 10.3, but not on Windows or OSX, or on Linux in 10.3+. Embarcadero is planning to drop object-based ARC on iOS and Android in 10.4.